# Отображение даты в pandas.plot

Tags: python, pandas

Есть массив данных формата:

index | value

2005-03-01 | 0.945535

2005-03-02 | 0.944586

2005-03-04 | 0.788801

2005-03-05 | 0.416701

2005-03-07 | 0.283472

Есть данные за несколько месяцев каждого года (например с марта по август), поэтому когда строю скользящее среднее получается такой график:

[image: Скользящее среднее переменной value]

**Вопрос**: как не отображать на оси Х тот период, когда данных нет. То есть последний месяц с данными 2005, а дальше сразу идет первый месяц с данными 2006.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()
index = np.union1d(pd.date_range(start='08/01/2005', end='03/01/2005', periods=100),
                   pd.date_range(start='08/01/2006', end='03/01/2006', periods=100))
loss_ss = pd.Series(rng.random(200), index=index)
loss_ss.rolling('30d').mean().plot()
```

Comment: Что  мешает вам создать датафрейм только со строками в которых нет отсутствующих данных и выводить на график этот вот датафрейм?

Comment: В датафрейме нет индексов с отсутствующими значениями для value. Есть ситуация когда идет дата 10-01-2005 с значенем, например 0.27, а следующий инстанс 03-01-2006, с значением 0.48. В данной ситуации, эти точки соединяются прямой, как видно на графике. Хотелось бы сохранить ось Х с датами и чтобы не было отступов между точками.

Comment: Индекс по датам удобен тем, что я могу в `pd.rolling` использовать окна разной длины при помощи 'Xd' (где X кол-во дней)

Comment: Тогда используйте для оси x не индекс. А индекс - для labels. То есть, для x - простой range  в длину данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, предложенный @strawdog:

```
index = np.union1d(pd.date_range(start='08/01/2005', end='03/01/2005', periods=100).date.astype('datetime64'),
                   pd.date_range(start='08/01/2006', end='03/01/2006', periods=100).date.astype('datetime64'))
loss_ss = pd.Series(rng.random(200), index=index)
plt.plot(loss_ss.rolling('30d').mean().values)
plt.xticks(range(0, 200, 20), index[range(0, 200, 20)])
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]